# how to pass the fetched data to the onclick function in the backticks

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch-api, template-literals

I am getting the songs data from the json file

```
const res = await fetch('./songApi/songs.json')
const fetchedSongs = await res.json()
entlet list = "";
fetchedSongs.map((song) => {
  list += `
    <div class="songitem" style="background:${song.background} ;">
    <img src=${song.coverpath} alt="agar tum sath ho">
    <span class="name">${song.SongName}</span>
    <span class="songlistplay">
    <span class="songTime">${song.time}</span>
    <i class="far fa-play-circle songitemplay" onClick="makeAllplays(${song})" ></i>
    </span>
    </div>`
})
```

onclick function

```
   makeAllplays(){}
```

but i can't pass the data and i got this ERROR:

```
     Unexpected identifier (at index.html:1:22)
```

Answer (score 1):

`song` is an object. So when you convert it to a string with `${song}` you get `[object Object]`.

If you want to include the whole `song` value in the `onclick` attribute, use JSON to convert it to an object literal.

```
onclick='makeAllPlays(${JSON.stringify(song)})'
```

Note that you have to use single quotes around the `onclick` attribute because JSON uses double quotes in the value.

Comment: this error i am facing when i use the above function Uncaught onclick='makeAllPlays(${JSON.stringify(song)})'    => SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at index.html:1:15)

Comment: If any of the strings in the `song` structure contain single quotes, this won't work, because those quotes will terminate the onclick attribute. If you need to handle this, you shouldn't generate HTML -- it doesn't have a way to escape delimiters. You need to use DOM methods to create the elements and set attributes. Another option would be to use an ID as the argument, and have the function look up the object in a global data structure.

Comment: See my answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72689801/how-to-pass-the-fetched-data-to-the-onclick-function-in-the-backticks/72689900?noredirect=1#comment128432622_72689900)